# ¿Como capturar la id correspondiente a la fila seleccionada desde un Datatable?

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

Quiero poder capturar la `id` correspondiente a una fila en mi `Server-side processing datatable`, para poder eliminar y actualizar los registros, por ahora solo llevo el poder eliminar y es que estoy atascado en un error que cuando yo selecciono un registro para eliminarlo, termina eliminando la última fila y cuando reviso por medio de un `die();` , resulta que la `id` que llega al query para eliminar la fila, es el `id` de la última final y no de la fila que seleccioné.

Me explico: al presionar el boton de eliminar en una fila x, siempre acaba eliminando la ultima fila del datatable, que podrá ser? me podrían ayudar?

El código para dibujar mi datatable:

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'modelo', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'marca',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'fecha_marcaje',   'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'id_equipo', 'dt' => 3, 
    'formatter' => function ($d, $row){

      return '<input type="hidden" name="id_equipo" value="' . $d . '"
              <center><button class="boton" type="button">Actualizar</button>    
              <button class="boton" type="submit">Eliminar</button></center>';

    })
);
```

El código en mi html en el formulario:

```
<script>
        // FUNCION PARA GENERAR EL DATATABLE
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "Data_tabla_ConsultaEquipos.php"
              } );
              } ); //FIN FUNCION

      //FUNCION PARA PREGUNTAR SI QUIERE ELIMINAR EL EQUIPO DESDE EL DATATABLE        
   function ConfirmarDelete()
          {
   var x = confirm("¿Seguro que quieres eliminar este equipo?");
      if (x)
   return true;
      else
   return false;
   } //FIN FUNCION
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br>
    <center><legend class="texto"><h1>CONSULTA / ACTUALIZACIÓN DE EQUIPOS REGISTRADOS</h1></legend></center>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <center><div style="width: 70%" align="center">
            <form onsubmit="return ConfirmarDelete()" action="eliminaEquipo.php" method="POST">
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="texto">Modelo</th>
            <th class="texto">Marca</th>
            <th class="texto">Fecha Marcaje</th>
            <th class="texto">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="texto">Modelo</th>
            <th class="texto">Marca</th>
            <th class="texto">Fecha Marcaje</th>
            <th class="texto">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
            </table></form></div></center>
```

El código donde tengo el query para eliminar un registro, donde siempre llega el `id` correspondiente al último registro mostrado en el `datatable`, y lo que quiero es que llegue el `id` que corresponde a la fila que verdaderamente seleccione.

```
<?php $db_host="localhost"; $db_user="root"; $db_password="";
$db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

if (!$db_connection) {
die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');}

$id_equipo = $_POST['id_equipo'];
print_r($id_equipo); // POR AQUI PUDE NOTAR QUE SIEMPRE ME LLEGA EL ID DE LA ULTIMA FILA DEL DATATABLE.

mysql_select_db("DB", $db_connection);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM equipos WHERE id_equipo = $id_equipo")
or die(mysql_error()); 

header("Location: ConsultarEquipos.php");?>
```

Comment: me parece que solo te esta tomando la ultima fila al armar el datatable??? se ve bien para todo el resto? podrias no poner como hidden esa columna y ver si el valor de cada fila es correcto?

Comment: el valor de cada columna està bien, las id mostradas corresponden a cada una de ellas, pero cuando pasa por el metodo POST hacia mi query para el DELETE, solo llega la ùltima id de la ultima fila, ajà.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listo, ya he resuelto el problema, lo que debía hacer era darle el valor del id al botón del submit, y ya agarra el id correspondiente a la fila seleccionada para eliminar. quedando así el código:

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'modelo', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'marca',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'fecha_marcaje',   'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'id_equipo', 'dt' => 3, 
    'formatter' => function ($d, $row){

      return '<center><button class="boton" type="button" id="ModalConsultaEquipos">Actualizar</button>    
              <button class="boton" name="id_equipo" type="submit" value="' . $d . '">Eliminar</button></center>';
    }) );
```